# No puedo ver los métodos disponibles en servicio web

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, iis

Tengo un servicio web en c# y .net 3.5, el cual al publicarlo de manera local a a través de una carpeta local y VS2019 puedo consultar los métodos que tiene el mismo sin ningún problema, pero necesito hacer un ajuste para que no muestre la descripción de los métodos.

Cuando ingreso la dirección **localhost:port/NombreServicio.asmx** me marca el error:

> "Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'."

Estuve buscando en la web y algunos colegas mencionan agregar las siguientes etiquetas: *HttpGet*, *HttpPost*, las cuales ya tengo agregadas pero me sigue marcando el mismo error. Alguien sabe a que se debe o me pueden dar alguna pista de por donde buscar?

De ante mano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

estuve revisando el código del proyecto y resulta que tenia otra etiqueta de mas en el archivo Web.config, la comenté y publique nuevamente el servicio de manera local y ya puedo ver los métodos y sus descripciones. Busqué mas información sobre esta etiqueta en el proyecto y parece que no se utiliza para nada. De igual forma subo estas anotaciones por si en algún momento alguien mas lo necesita.

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
        <!--<remove name="Documentation" />-->
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

¡Saludos!